# Why static_assert error: "expression must have a constant value" even if I do pass constants?

Tags: c++, comparison, constants, static-assert

This piece of code is compiled with no issues:

```
const int tmp1 = 1, tmp2 = 1;
const bool cmp = (tmp1 == tmp2);
static_assert(cmp, "OK");
```

This one is fine, too:

```
const bool cmp = (HUGE_VALF == HUGE_VALF);
static_assert(cmp, "OK");
```

This one is not:

```
const auto tmp = HUGE_VALF;
const bool cmp = (tmp == tmp);
static_assert(cmp, "OK");   // <-- error
```

> Error: expression must have a constant value.
>   The value of variable "cmp" cannot be used as a constant

Same behaviour with `static const`.

What is wrong? `HUGE_VALF` is a preprocessor macro, i.e. constant, and `cmp` is with no doubt a compile time constant...

Environment:
Microsoft Windows 10
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 & 2019

Comment: Switch to `constexpr`. For some types, being constant is not enough to be a constant expression.

Comment: `const bool cmp` is still a variable, whose value cannot be changed.

Comment: What does `HUGE_VALF` expand to?

Comment: @frogatto - It expands to a special value that represent an infinite value.

Answer (score 0):

With this test program I got to the problem:

```
#include <cmath>

constexpr auto val1 = 1.23f;
constexpr auto val2 = HUGE_VALF;

static_assert(val1 == val1, "OK");
static_assert(val2 == val2, "OK");

int main()
{
}
```

Result:

- Visual C++ 2019 32 bits: OK
- Visual C++ 2019 64 bits: OK
- Visual C++ 2013 32 bits: OK
- Visual C++ 2013 64 bits: Failed

Output:

```
1>  TestConstexpr.cpp(5): error C2144: syntax error : 'auto' should be preceded by ';'
1>  TestConstexpr.cpp(5): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>  TestConstexpr.cpp(6): error C2144: syntax error : 'auto' should be preceded by ';'
1>  TestConstexpr.cpp(6): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>  TestConstexpr.cpp(6): error C2086: 'int constexpr' : redefinition
1>          TestConstexpr.cpp(5) : see declaration of 'constexpr'
1>  TestConstexpr.cpp(8): error C2057: expected constant expression
1>  TestConstexpr.cpp(9): error C2057: expected constant expression
```

Comment: Conclusion: Visual C++ 2013 is old and buggy, don't use that (at least with newer features)?

Comment: @DanM. - Not easy to do when you are not in charge of the development strategy. Anyway, I let them know...